# Can a Snowflake materialized view contain flatten of semi-structured data?

Tags: flatten, materialized-views, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The end of this article suggests that a materialized view can contain flatten ... https://www.snowflake.com/blog/snowflake-materialized-views-a-fast-zero-maintenance-accurate-solution/
But if I try it I get an error ... "More than one table referenced in the view definition"
Anybody got any examples of how to create a MV with flatten?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_SOMETHING
AS
SELECT
    F.ID,
    A.VALUE:Type::string                    AS ATTRIBUTE_TYPE,
    A.VALUE:Value::string                   AS ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
FROM
    FRAME F
    , lateral flatten(input => F.ENVIRONMENT) A;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works fine for me.  You need `FLATTEN()` for ARRAYs, but not for OBJECTs.
Maybe you are mixing the two?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE T AS
SELECT 1 ID, ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(1, 2, 3) A, OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('X', 2, 'Y', 3) O;

CREATE OR REPLACE MATERIALIZED VIEW T_MV AS
SELECT
    ID,
    O:X::NUMBER O_X,
    O:Y::NUMBER O_Y,
    VALUE A
FROM T, LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => A);
```